Tensorflow C++ Tensor.SubSlice(1)
I am coding my own neural network with tensorflow c++ api. I have a tensor with all data with shape [65000, 784] and reshaped it to tensor with shape [2031, 32, 784] to use it as batches. To use the batches i use SubSlice for tensorflow to get each batch of shape [32, 784]. But the second one with             Tensor imageBatch(imageBatches.SubSlice(num)); //num = 1, evokes error 2024-04-21 22:27:18.856998: F ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:888] Check failed: IsAligned() ptr = 0x55555569f130
. Can anyone help?
This is my code snippet
for (int num = 0; num < dataSize; num++) {
            vector<Tensor> output1;
            //auto d1 = DeepCopy(scope, imageBatches.SubSlice(num));
            //auto d2 = DeepCopy(scope, labelBatches.SubSlice(num));
            //TF_CHECK_OK(session->Run({d1, d2}, &output1));
            Tensor imageBatch(imageBatches.SubSlice(num));
            Tensor labelBatch(labelBatches.SubSlice(num));
            //std::cout << "Image batch: " << imageBatch.matrix<float>() << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "imageBatch shape: " << imageBatch.shape().DebugString() << ", labelBatch shape: " << labelBatch.shape().DebugString() <<std::endl;
            TF_CHECK_OK(session->Run({{*features, imageBatch}, {*this->labels, labelBatch}}, apply_gradients, {}, nullptr));
        }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The error message you're encountering, "Check failed: IsAligned() ptr," suggests that there's an issue with memory alignment when accessing the data in the Tensor object. This typically occurs when the memory address accessed is not aligned to the required alignment.TensorFlow C++ API requires tensors to be aligned properly in memory. Ensure that the memory used to store the data in the Tensor object is aligned correctly. You can try using TensorFlow's AlignedMalloc function to allocate memory with proper alignment.Check SubSlice Parameters,Memory Access Issues
